# Ubuntu 18.04 Suddenly Fails to Boot

Tags: boot, 18.04

I have been following this guide [Link](https://linuxconfig.org/install-and-set-up-kvm-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux) to set up KVM on my machine with Ubuntu 18.04. Ubuntu has been working perfectly on this machine with Ryzen 3700x and Radeon VEGA 64.

Without modifying anything critical but only the network interface configurations, namely editing /etc/network/interfaces, I rebooted to let the modification take place, only to find that Ubuntu somehow fails to boot. A black screen is all. I tried to switch to different console for information, but there is nothing but a blinking cursor.

All consoles have this same appearance.

[image: All consoles have this same appearance]

The Windows 10 installed on another partition of the hard drive can boot and run normally, but the Ubuntu cannot be accessed no matter what. Since there are no error information printed, I have no clue at all what this problem is and how to solve it.

An information that might be a hint is that when booting Windows after trying to boot Ubuntu, it prompted to run a disk check.

Comment: Does holding Shift Key bring up Recovery Mode Selection at Boot?

Comment: Also your last Statement it appears you have mixed UEFI and Non-UEFI installations.